# Function parameter semantics (with nested functions)

Tags: python, nested-function

I'm learning python and I am stumbling over trying to understand how Python handles closures. I generally understand this to be a free-variable is stored in memory to be accessed long after the callee scope has expired. I am confused as to how this kind of setup is resolved.

```
def do_something(x):
    return lambda y: y + x;
f = do_something(4);
f(4)
```

Here f(4) seems to use the lambda function signature instead of the do_something signature.
It returns 8, but what internally causes python to use y instead of x as the input parameter? Should I think of `do_something` similarly to a class definition, where `f = do_something(4)` is a constructor and `f(4)` is the actual action to take?

See [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) for where I first encountered this.

Comment: Did you mean to say `f(y)` instead of `do_something(y)`?

Comment: There are two separate functions here, one of which returns the other. `do_something` has `x` as a parameter while the lambda has `y`.

Comment: Sorry edited to perhaps be more clear

Comment: Now it's even worse. Which one do you think is the constructor, which one do you think is the action?

Comment: I think the f = do_something(x) is the constructor, as f(4) seems to be using the signature from the lambda function.

Comment: I guess then that's where my confusion is, since to me `f` seems to be a function pointer-like thing to do_something.

Comment: @d4r3llo5 No, `f` contains what `do_something` **returns**, it doesn't contain a reference to `do_something` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `lambda y: y + x` creates a new function, and this function is returned by `do_something` to its caller. In this function, `x` is a free variable, and the closure saves a reference to the parameter to the `do_something` function that was used to create it. So when you call

```
f = do_something(4)
```

it's equivalent to:

```
f = lambda y: y + 4
```

which is equivalent to:

```
def f(y):
    return y + 4
```

Then when you call `f(4)` it calls that function, binding `y` to the `f` parameter.

You're correct that this is similar to the way class constructors work; in some programming languages, closures are used as the internal implementation of class instances. Classes add things like inheritance, and also typically provide easier syntax to declare the class properties and methods.

Comment: So basically the function `do_something` is replaced by the lambda function in all future calls of variable 'f'. In your example, `f = lambda y: y + 4`, it would be assumed that y is initialized to 0 then, right? Is the semantics for having an outer method `do_something` just for the functionality of the closure?

Comment: `do_something` isn't replaced by anything. In general `x = func(y)` means to call `func`, and assign whatever it returns to `x`. `do_something` returns a function, and that function is assigned to `f`.

Comment: `y` is initialized to the argument of `f`.

Answer (score 0):

Function objects have an attribute that stores the values in a "cell".  You can access the closed-over variables from the `__closure__` attribute:

```
>>> def do_something(x):
...     return lambda y: y + x;
... 
>>> f = do_something(4)
>>> f.__closure__[0]
<cell at 0x105d86600: int object at 0x7f905ac12bd0>
```

This doesn't seem all that helpful.  Luckily, it's easy to get the cell's contents too:

```
>>> f.__closure__[0].cell_contents
4
```

Ok, that's only the first part of the puzzle (how does python store the closed over data).  Lets look at the disassembled bytecode for `f` to see what python is doing with this data:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (y)
              3 LOAD_DEREF               0 (x)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

The first code `LOAD_FAST` is what is used to load a local variable (stored as an array of pointers to objects in C -- the `0` indicates that this is the first object in the array).  In this case `y` is a local variable since it's in the function's signature.  The next code is [`LOAD_DEREF`]([enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_DEREF)) which actually looks in the cell and to load the value from the closure.  And that completes the picture for this problem at a low level ...

At a higher level, you don't need to worry about any of this.  All you need to know is that a python function is able to look up the values of any scope that encloses it.